# Converting Keras to Pytorch

Tags: machine-learning, keras, pytorch

I am trying to convert the following model to pytorch:

```
def get_model():

    model = keras.models.Sequential()

    model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu', padding='same', input_shape=(9,9,1)))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(1,1), activation='relu', padding='same'))

    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(81*9))
    model.add(Reshape((-1, 9)))
    model.add(Activation('softmax'))
    
    return model

model = get_model()

adam = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=.001)
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=adam)

model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=32, epochs=2)
```

from https://github.com/shivaverma/Sudoku-Solver/blob/master/model.py

```
class Conv2dSame(torch.nn.Module):
def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size, padding, bias=True, padding_layer=torch.nn.ReflectionPad2d):
    """It only support square kernels and stride=1, dilation=1, groups=1."""
    super(Conv2dSame, self).__init__()
    self.net = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv2d(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size, bias=bias, padding=padding),
        nn.ReLU(True),
    )
def forward(self, x):
    return self.net(x)
```

class CNN(torch.nn.Module):

```
def __init__(self, hidden_channels, batch_size):

    super(CNN, self).__init__()
    self.hidden_channels = hidden_channels
    self.batch_size = batch_size

    self.embed = nn.Sequential(
        
        Conv2dSame(1, hidden_channels, 3, 1),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(hidden_channels),
        Conv2dSame(hidden_channels, hidden_channels, 3, 1),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(hidden_channels),
        Conv2dSame(hidden_channels, 2*hidden_channels, 1, 0),

    )

    self.out = nn.Sequential( 
        
        nn.Linear(2*hidden_channels*81, 81*9),
        
    )

    self.softmax = nn.Softmax(dim=1)

def forward(self, x):
    embed = self.embed(x)
    embed = embed.view(-1, 2*self.hidden_channels*81)
    out = self.out(embed).view(-1,9,81)
    return self.softmax(out)
```

But it doesn't seem to be working with:

```
model = CNN(hidden_channels=64,batch_size=32) # GCN(hidden_channels=64)
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001) #0.01
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

def train():

    model.train()

    for batch_i, data in tqdm(enumerate(train_loader)):  # Iterate in batches over the training dataset.

      optimizer.zero_grad()  # Clear gradients.

      unsolved = data[0]
      solved = data[1]

      out = model(unsolved) # data.x, data.edge_index, data.batch)  # Perform a single forward pass.
      loss = criterion(out, solved)  # Compute the loss.
      if batch_i % 100 == 0:
        print(loss)

      loss.backward()  # Derive gradients.
      optimizer.step()  # Update parameters based on gradients.

batch_size = 32 #64
num_epochs = 2

train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True, num_workers=0)

for _ in range(num_epochs):
  train()
```

My loss stays very stagnant and my accuracy is bad. I know the keras code works fine. Please let me know if there is any part of the keras code I am misunderstanding. Or if my pytorch implementation is off. I am very new to keras (and pytorch). Thank you!

Comment: 3 quick things: 1. Your first code goes [Conv - ReLU - batch norm], but your pytorch code goes [Conv - batch norm - ReLU], 2. You use bias before a batch norm layer, which is generally not recommended, and 3. Your reshapes are different, is this intentional?

Comment: Great catch with the relu and batchnorm! I have updated my code but it still doesn't seem to work :/. The reshapes are intentional cause keras seems to have channels last but pytorch has channels first. In terms of the bias, I am pretty sure the bias is also in the keras code, no?

Answer (score 0):

My attempt is below. In your keras code, you squeeze it to a different shape (-1,9) so I assume that your labels are also in that format. Therefore you need to do the same thing in your pytorch code.

```
import keras
from keras.layers import Activation
from keras.layers import Conv2D, BatchNormalization, Dense, Flatten, Reshape

def get_model_keras():

    model = keras.models.Sequential()

    model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu', padding='same', input_shape=(9,9,1)))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(1,1), activation='relu', padding='same'))

    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(81*9))
    model.add(Reshape((-1, 9)))
    model.add(Activation('softmax'))
    
    return model

import torch
from torch import nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
 
class get_model_pytorch(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels, hidden_channels,kernel_size):
        super(get_model_pytorch, self).__init__()
        self.in_channels = in_channels
        self.hidden_channels = hidden_channels
        self.kernel_size = kernel_size

        self.embed = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(self.in_channels,self.hidden_channels,
                      self.kernel_size,padding=self.kernel_size//2, bias=False),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(self.hidden_channels),
            nn.Conv2d(self.hidden_channels,self.hidden_channels,
                      self.kernel_size,padding=self.kernel_size//2, bias=False),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(self.hidden_channels),
            nn.Conv2d(self.hidden_channels,self.hidden_channels*2,
                      1,padding=0, bias=False),
            nn.ReLU()
            )      
        self.out = nn.Sequential(        
            nn.Linear(2*hidden_channels*81, 81*9),
            )
    def forward(self, x):
        embed = self.embed(x)
        embed = embed.view(-1, 2*self.hidden_channels*81)
        out = self.out(embed).view(-1,9)
        return F.softmax(out,dim=1)
```

Comment: This is great, thank you! I am giving it a try right now. I had to change this line back to out = self.out(embed).view(-1,9) -> out = self.out(embed).view(-1,9, 81) because my target is [32,81] and that the only way it seems to work with nn.CrossEntropyLoss. (I am pretty sure the labels in the keras code are a different shape)

Comment: Ok, so that means you should change it to .view(-1,81). I'm assuming your batch size is 32?

Comment: It seems to converge slightly around a loss of 1.58. this is better than I had before, but the keras code seems to never really stop all the way down to ~0.6

Comment: I'm trying to match your keras code, and so it seems that there is an inconsistency there. I think the answer lies in the way it processes its loss.

Comment: When I change it to .view(-1,81), I get ValueError: Expected input batch_size (288) to match target batch_size (32).

Comment: It uses sparse cross entropy. That is the same as nn.CrossEntropy loss yes?

Comment: I think so, yes. It could be that the loss is calculated differently. Are the accuracies comparable at all?

Comment: Not really. I get about 40/2000. Its supposed to get 1990/2000.

Comment: But in solving whole sudoku puzzles, 40 isnt bad. most are just a few numbers off